# Stock Alerts Laravel-9/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-8

I want to create a function on key up click that should rise the message `Selling Quantity is more than Quantity in Stock` I tried the below code

I am getting the data using ajax request and there is a read-only column that shows the total product count in stock which works perfectly.
I am adding multiple invoices to dynamically adding row list the only problem I am facing is that I don't know how to check each product count when I add it to the list of the invoice should not be greater than the stock it only checks the first row did not check the other rows.

**Here I am checking the stock quantity and selling quantity**

```
  <script id="document-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
       <td> <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control selling_qty text-right" name="selling_qty[]" value=""> </td> 

          <td> <input type="number" class="form-control unit_price text-right" name="unit_price[]" value="">  </td>
     </script>



<script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).on('keyup click','.unit_price,.selling_qty', function() {  
      var current_stock_qty = $('#current_stock_qty').val(); 
      var seling_qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('.selling_qty').val();     
       if(current_stock_qty < seling_qty) { 
       $.notify("Selling Quantity is
      Grather then Quantity in Stock " , { globalPosition: 'top right',
      className: 'error' }); } }); }); // end here 
  </script>
```

`current_stock_qty` value is changed when I chose a different product the problem is that it checks the condition only with first-row `current_stock_qty` not with each of them when I add the items for example when I chose cement it gave me 3 which is the correct `current_stock_qty` when I chose another product like steel which `current_stock_qty` is 10 it gives me to correct quantity but the problem is that it checks the condition only with first-row `current_stock_qty` which was cement not with each of item ,when the `selling_qty` becomes greater than a first product which is `cement` it starts popping the message while I am adding the second product and want to run the condition as per the quantity of each product.

**add_invoice Blade html code**

```
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="md-3">
                        <label for="example-text-input" class="form-label">Product Name </label>
                        <select name="product_id" id="product_id" class="form-select select2"
                            aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option selected="">Open this select menu</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="md-3">
                        <label for="example-text-input" class="form-label">Stock(Pic/Kg)</label>
                        <input class="form-control example-date-input" name="current_stock_qty" type="text"
                            id="current_stock_qty" readonly style="background-color:#ddd">

                    </div>
                </div>




<div class="card-body">
                <form method="post" action="{{ route('invoice.store') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <table class="table-sm table-bordered" width="100%" style="border-color: #ddd;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="7%">PSC/KG</th>    
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody id="addRow" class="addRow">
                             // here the input will generated 
                        </tbody>

                        <tbody>      
                        </tbody>
                    </table><br>
```

Comment: `current_stock_qty <seling_qty` probably a typo, add a space after the `<`  and I don't think there's a keyup click. There's a keyup and a click, but not both

Comment: UnderDog there isn't any problem with the `Keyup click` nor with `<`

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML that is referenced by your code. A wild guess is that you have duplicate HTML `id` attributes, which makes your HTML invalid. Not your question, but properly indenting code is a first good habit any serious coder wants to adhere to.

Comment: There is no "unit_price" or "selling_qty" in that piece of HTML. I understand it would be added dynamically (?), but please focus your question on (the smallest) HTML with which the problem can be reproduced. With the HTML you have provided the event would never fire. Please also remove HTML that is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: trincot you are right it is added dynamically  which is in javascript section I have updated please check it

Comment: Can you please *reduce* all of that code to only focus on the problem? Remove the dynamic part, and present the *resulting* HTML, and only the HTML that is relevant for the problem. If I understand correctly, there is no problem with the Ajax code, so remove it. But instead present the situation where the dynamic part is already loaded, and the user clicks...

Comment: I don't see an HTML element with the id `current_stock_qty`.

Comment: please check I have updated the question

Comment: Your code has `find(".selling_qty")`, but there is none in your HTML (except a template). I am giving up.

Comment: Thanks as you know it creates a list of items I mean array is there any way to loop through array and find the seling qty and then check it with stock I don't know exactly because I am really weak in javascript